# When i running the multiple execute statement service i got the error "Cannot read property "parameters" from null "

Tags: database, business-process-management, ibm-bpm

I want to insert the below default values when i am running the service i got this below error any one please tell me how to resolve.

**Runtime error in script ("Process: 'CustomPersonalGS Practice' ProcessItem: 'Initialize' Type: 'ITEM'" -1:-1).TypeError: Cannot read property "parameters" from null**

[image]

[image]

```html
//Initialise SQL Query List
tw.local.sqlQueries =  new tw.object.listOf.SQLStatement();
tw.local.sql = "";

tw.local.customerPD = new tw.object.customerPD1BO();
tw.local.customerPD.customerPersonalDetailsList = new tw.object.listOf.customerSpecificPersonalDetailsListBO();
var custPersonalDetails = new tw.object.customerSpecificPersonalDetailsListBO();
custPersonalDetails.customerId = "8467";
custPersonalDetails.custPersonalDetailsId = "8";
custPersonalDetails.isBPMEnabled = true;
custPersonalDetails.isCCPEnabled = true;
custPersonalDetails.isCCPMandatory = true;
custPersonalDetails.isLatestVersion = true
tw.local.customerPD.customerPersonalDetailsList.insertIntoList(tw.local.customerPD.customerPersonalDetailsList.listLength, custPersonalDetails);


tw.local.sql = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMPERSONALDETAILSQUESTION(CUSTOMERID,CUSTPERSONLADETAILSID,ISBPMENABLED,ISCCPENABLED,ISCCPMANDATORY,ISLATESTVERSION) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?) ";

function addSQLStatement() {
  tw.local.sqlQueries[tw.local.sqlQueries.listLength] = new tw.object.SQLStatement();
}

function addParam(value,type,mode) {
  log.info("VALUE :" + value);
  var newParam = new tw.object.SQLParameter();
  newParam.value = value;
  newParam.type = type;
  newParam.mode = mode;
     if( tw.local.sqlQueries == null){
         tw.local.sqlQueries = new tw.object.listOf.SQLStatement();
     }
    if( tw.local.sqlQueries[tw.local.sqlQueries.listLength] == null ){
         tw.local.sqlQueries.insertIntoList(tw.local.sqlQueries.listLength, new tw.object.SQLStatement());
    }
    if(tw.local.sqlQueries[tw.local.sqlQueries.listLength].parameters == null ){
        tw.local.sqlQueries[tw.local.sqlQueries.listLength].parameters = new tw.object.listOf.SQLParameter();
    }
  var paramsLength = tw.local.sqlQueries[tw.local.sqlQueries.listLength].parameters.listLength;
  tw.local.sqlQueries[tw.local.sqlQueries.listLength].parameters[paramsLength] = newParam;
}

for(var i=0;i<tw.local.customerPD.customerPersonalDetailsList.listLength;i++){
    addSQLStatement(tw.local.sql);
 addParam(tw.local.customerPD.customerPersonalDetailsList[i].customerId,"VARCHAR","IN");
 addParam(tw.local.customerPD.customerPersonalDetailsList[i].custPersonalDetailsId,"VARCHAR","IN");
 var yesNoFlag = "N";
 if(tw.local.customerPD.customerPersonalDetailsList[i].isBPMEnabled){
  yesNoFlag="Y"; 
  addParam(yesNoFlag,"CHAR","IN");
 }
 yesNoFlag = "N";
 if(tw.local.customerPD.customerPersonalDetailsList[i].isCCPEnabled){
  yesNoFlag="Y"; 
  addParam(yesNoFlag,"CHAR","IN");
 }
 yesNoFlag = "N";
 if(tw.local.customerPD.customerPersonalDetailsList[i].isCCPMandatory){
  yesNoFlag="Y"; 
  addParam(yesNoFlag,"CHAR","IN");
 }
 yesNoFlag = "N";
 if(tw.local.customerPD.customerPersonalDetailsList[i].isLatestVersion){
  yesNoFlag="Y"; 
  addParam(yesNoFlag,"CHAR","IN");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize the parameter list in your SQL as far as I can tell.  That is on line 38 you call -

```
  var paramsLength = tw.local.sqlQueries[tw.local.sqlQueries.listLength].parameters.listLength;
```

However when you create the entry in the tw.local.sqlQueries, you didn't initialize the parameter array.  I'll also note that your addSQLStatement() function ignore the sql input (and that value is hard coded, so really you don't need to pass it in).  I think if you change addSQLStatement to be something like -

```
function addSQLStatement(query) {
  var targetQuery = new tw.object.SQLStatement();
  targetQuery.sql = query;
  tagetQuery.params = new tw.object.listOf.SQLParameter();
  tw.local.sqlQueries[tw.local.sqlQueries.listLength] = targetQuery;
}
```

then your code will work.  Additionally you could actually return targetQuery from this function and then pass it to the "addParams" method eliminating the need to find the last one in the array.  Alternatively insert it in the beginning of the array instead and just update the 0th item instead of the last.

-AP

Answer (score 0):

This comparison will never work properly. `array[array.length]` will always be `null` (line 35).

```
if (tw.local.sqlQueries[tw.local.sqlQueries.listLength].parameters == null ){
```

In addition, in the next lines, if you want to work with the last element of the list, you might want to use something like `array[array.length - 1]`. Personally, I'd use some temporary variable, do some stuff with it and insert it into the list at the end (similar to [@Drux's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683848/767160)).